# pygame collissions between two groups

Tags: pygame, sprite

I still have a problem with my software to check collisions between spaceship and asteroids. I have got no idea why I get a collision only in the top left corner of the screen.

any ideas ? any help please ?

```
import pygame, sys
import random
import math
from pygame.locals import KEYDOWN, K_SPACE

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("ASTROCRASH version 0.1 >>> DKR103 <<<")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

SCREENH = 600
SCREENW = 800
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENW, SCREENH))

sGRAD = math.pi/180

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BBB = (0, 75, 230)

ASTEROIDS = []
MISSILES = []
SPACESHIPS = []

class AsteroidSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,posX,posY):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)    
        self.image = pygame.image.load("img/asteroid3.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = posX
        self.y = posY
        self.speed = 2
        self.dx = random.choice([1,-1]) * self.speed * random.random()
        self.dy = random.choice([1,-1]) * self.speed * random.random()

    def update(self):
        if self.y > SCREENH:
            self.y = (0 - self.rect[3])
        if self.y < (0 - self.rect[3]):
            self.y = SCREENH
        if self.x > SCREENW:
            self.x = (0 - self.rect[2])
        if self.x < (0 - self.rect[2]):
            self.x = SCREENW

        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy

class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #load original image
        self.imageMaster = pygame.image.load("img/spaceship.png")
        self.imageMaster = self.imageMaster.convert()
        ###self.imageMaster.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        #set Sprite attribute
        self.image = self.imageMaster
        #get Sprite rect
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ((SCREEN.get_width()/2),(SCREEN.get_height()/2))
        #initial rotation value
        self.dir = 0
        #ship movement speed
        self.speed = 5

    def rotation(self):
        #set Sprite center before rotation
        self.oldCenter = self.rect.center
        #rotate Sprite
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.imageMaster,self.dir)
        self.rect= self.image.get_rect()
        #set new Sprite center equal to old Center so it stays in place
        self.rect.center = self.oldCenter
        self.value = self.dir * math.pi / 180
    def update(self):
        #move
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:

            self.rect[0] -= self.speed * math.sin(self.value)
            self.rect[1] -= self.speed * math.cos(self.value)

        #rotate
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.dir += 5
            if self.dir > 360:
                self.dir = 15
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.dir -= 5
            if self.dir < 0:
                self.dir = 355
        #outside SCREEN conditions
        if self.rect[1] > SCREENH:
            self.rect[1] = (0 - self.rect[3])
        if self.rect[1] < (0 - self.rect[3]):
            self.rect[1] = SCREENH
        if self.rect[0] > SCREENW:
            self.rect[0] = (0 - self.rect[2])
        if self.rect[0] < (0 - self.rect[2]):
            self.rect[0] = SCREENW

    def draw(self):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image,(self.rect[0],self.rect[1]))

def main():
    #spaceship
    spaceship = Ship()
    SPACESHIPS.append(spaceship)
    for i in range(8):
        ASTEROIDS.append(AsteroidSprite(300,300))

    runGame = True   
    while runGame:

        clock.tick(60)
        SCREEN.fill(BLACK)      

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                runGame = False

        #update asteroids
        for i in range(8):
            ASTEROIDS[i].update()
            SCREEN.blit(ASTEROIDS[i].image,(ASTEROIDS[i].x,ASTEROIDS[i].y))
        for a in ASTEROIDS:
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(a,SPACESHIPS,0):
                SCREEN.fill(BBB)  

        spaceship.rotation()       
        spaceship.update()
        spaceship.draw()
        print spaceship.rect[0]

        pygame.display.update()                          
main()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) function finds collisions between all sprites of the two passed sprite-groups and **returns a dictionary** containing the collision information, as the documentation states.

Because the collision is determined by **comparing the `sprite.rect` attribute** of each sprite, every time you call an `update()` method of an sprite instance you need to update the **position of `self.rect` object**, instead of changing its `self.x` and `self.y` attributes.

Your **`Ship` class** is ok, because you **change the `self.rect` object and its own `.x` or `.y` attributes**. (e.g. `self.rect[1] = (0 - self.rect[3])`).
But in your **`AsteroidSprite` class** you create a rect object in the `__init__()` method and only **change the `self.x` and `self.y` attributes** of an instance when you call the `.update()` method.

What you need to change:

1. The `.update()` method of the `AsteroidSprite` class, because **you need to change the `self.rect` objects position, which is used for collision detection**.
2. The `if` statement where you check for a collision, because **`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()` returns a dict object, not a Boolean value**.

I hope this helps you a little bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks. Your answer helped me to solve the problem.

updated code:

```
import pygame, sys
import random
import math
from pygame.locals import KEYDOWN, K_SPACE

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("ASTROCRASH version 0.1 >>> DKR103 <<<")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

SCREENH = 600
SCREENW = 800
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENW, SCREENH))

sGRAD = math.pi/180

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BBB = (0, 75, 230)

ASTEROIDS = []
MISSILES = []
SPACESHIPS = []

class AsteroidSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,posX,posY):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)    
        self.image = pygame.image.load("img/asteroid3.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = posX
        self.rect.y = posY
        self.speed = 2
        self.dx = random.choice([1,-1]) * self.speed * random.random()
        self.dy = random.choice([1,-1]) * self.speed * random.random()

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.y > SCREENH:
            self.rect.y = (0 - self.rect[3])
        if self.rect.y < (0 - self.rect[3]):
            self.rect.y = SCREENH
        if self.rect.x > SCREENW:
            self.rect.x = (0 - self.rect[2])
        if self.rect.x < (0 - self.rect[2]):
            self.rect.x = SCREENW

        self.rect.x += self.dx
        self.rect.y += self.dy

class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #load original image
        self.imageMaster = pygame.image.load("img/spaceship.png")
        self.imageMaster = self.imageMaster.convert()
        ###self.imageMaster.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        #set Sprite attribute
        self.image = self.imageMaster
        #get Sprite rect
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ((SCREEN.get_width()/2),(SCREEN.get_height()/2))
        #initial rotation value
        self.dir = 0
        #ship movement speed
        self.speed = 5

    def rotation(self):
        #set Sprite center before rotation
        self.oldCenter = self.rect.center
        #rotate Sprite
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.imageMaster,self.dir)
        self.rect= self.image.get_rect()
        #set new Sprite center equal to old Center so it stays in place
        self.rect.center = self.oldCenter
        self.value = self.dir * math.pi / 180
    def update(self):
        #move
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:

            self.rect[0] -= self.speed * math.sin(self.value)
            self.rect[1] -= self.speed * math.cos(self.value)

        #rotate
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.dir += 5
            if self.dir > 360:
                self.dir = 15
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.dir -= 5
            if self.dir < 0:
                self.dir = 355
        #outside SCREEN conditions
        if self.rect[1] > SCREENH:
            self.rect[1] = (0 - self.rect[3])
        if self.rect[1] < (0 - self.rect[3]):
            self.rect[1] = SCREENH
        if self.rect[0] > SCREENW:
            self.rect[0] = (0 - self.rect[2])
        if self.rect[0] < (0 - self.rect[2]):
            self.rect[0] = SCREENW

    def draw(self):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image,(self.rect[0],self.rect[1]))

def main():
    #spaceship
    spaceship = Ship()
    SPACESHIPS.append(spaceship)
    for i in range(8):
        ASTEROIDS.append(AsteroidSprite(300,300))

    runGame = True   
    while runGame:

        clock.tick(60)
        SCREEN.fill(BLACK)      

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                runGame = False

        #update asteroids
        for i in range(8):
            ASTEROIDS[i].update()
            SCREEN.blit(ASTEROIDS[i].image,(ASTEROIDS[i].rect.x,ASTEROIDS[i].rect.y))
        for a in ASTEROIDS:
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(a,SPACESHIPS,0):
                SCREEN.fill(BBB)  

        spaceship.rotation()       
        spaceship.update()
        spaceship.draw()
        print spaceship.rect[0]

        pygame.display.update()                          
main()
pygame.quit()
```